# Exoplayer - Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved

Tags: android, maven, gradle, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

There are tons of questions with a similar title, I know. I've been through them all, tried all the proposed solutions but nothing helped.

I have an Android library with a few `Exoplayer` dependencies. My library is published on `JCenter` for a couple of years now and everything works fine. Now `JCenter` is shutting down and I migrated to `MavenCentral/Sonatype`.

I added [gradle-maven-publish-plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin) to upload and publish my library to `Sonatype`. I made no changes to my code apart from upgrading the `Android Gradle Plugin` from `3.5.1` to `4.0.0` and of course applying the dependencies that the newly added `gradle-maven-publish-plugin` requires.

The structure is as follows. My library contains a class:

```
open class BasePlayer: Player.EventListener, AdEvent.AdEventListener, AdErrorEvent.AdErrorListener
```

And in my app I extend this class:

```
class MyPlayer: BasePlayer
```

Now when I add the new artifact from `MavenCentral/Sonatype` to my project, the project builds and my library files are accessible but not the `Exoplayer` dependencies. I get the following error(s):

```
Cannot access 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$EventListener' which is a supertype of 'com.test.playground.myapplication.MyPlayer'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdEvent$AdEventListener' which is a supertype of 'com.test.playground.myapplication.MyPlayer'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3.api.AdErrorEvent$AdErrorListener' which is a supertype of 'com.test.playground.myapplication.MyPlayer'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

And yes, the `Exoplayer` dependencies in my library are added using `api` and not `implementation` - as I mentioned this library has been live on `JCenter` for a couple of years now.

Any thoughts? I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now. If you need more info, just leave a comment - I'll be here, refreshing this page like a maniac :)

Comment: Hi! Do u find solution?